# How do I construct an object in Perl6 from a hash?

Tags: raku, object-construction

In Perl5 you can do something like this:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;

package Local::Class {
  use Moo;
  has [qw( x y )] => ( is => 'ro');
  sub BUILDARGS { shift; return (@_) ? (@_ > 1) ? { @_ } : shift : {} }
}

use Local::Class;

# Create object directly
my $x = Local::Class->new( x => 1, y => 10 );
say $x->x, ' ', $x->y; # 1 10

# Arguments from a hash
my %hash = ( x => 5, y => 20 );
$x = Local::Class->new(%hash);
say $x->x, ' ', $x->y; # 5 20

# Arguments from a hash reference
$x = Local::Class->new(\%hash);
say $x->x, ' ', $x->y; # 5 20
```

The two calls in the bottom work the same because of the custom `BUILDARGS` method, which basically turns them both into the sort of hash references expected by Moo(se)?.

But how can I do the same in Perl6?

```perl6
#!/usr/bin/env perl6

class Local::Class {
  has $.x;
  has $.y;
}

my $x;

# This works
$x = Local::Class.new( x => 1, y => 10 );
say $x.x, ' ', $x.y; # 1 10

# This doesn't
my %hash = %( x => 5, y => 20 );
$x = Local::Class.new(%hash);

# This doesn't either
$x = Local::Class.new(item(%hash));

# Both die with:
# Default constructor for 'Local::Class' only takes named arguments
```

So how can I take a hash that has been created elsewhere, and convert it into the sort of named arguments needed by the default constructor of a class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Using the default constructor

The default `.new` constructor maps **named** arguments to public attributes.

In your example, you pass a hash as a **positional** argument. You can use the `|` syntax to interpolate the hash entries into the argument list as named arguments:

```perl
$x = Local::Class.new(|%hash);
```

However, note that this will cause problems if your class has an array attribute like `has @.z`:

```perl
class Local::Class {
    has $.x;
    has $.y;
    has @.z;
}

my %hash = x => 5, y => 20, z => [1, 2];
my $x = Local::Class.new(|%hash);

say $x;  # Local::Class.new(x => 5, y => 20, z => [[1, 2],])
```

This is because like all hashes, `%hash` places each of its values in an item container. So the attribute will be initialized as `@.z = $([1, 2])`, which results in an array of a single element which is the original array.

One way to avoid this, is to use a [`Capture`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Capture.html) instead of a `Hash`:

```perl
my $capture = \( x => 5, y => 20, z => [1, 2] );
my $x = Local::Class.new(|$capture);

say $x;  # Local::Class.new(x => 5, y => 20, z => [1, 2])
```

Or use a `Hash` but then de-containerize its values with `<>` and turn the whole thing into a [`Map`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Map.html) (which, unlike a `Hash`, won't add back the item containers) before interpolating it into the argument list:

```perl
my %hash = x => 5, y => 20, z => [1, 2];
my $x = Local::Class.new(|Map.new: (.key => .value<> for %hash));

say $x;  # Local::Class.new(x => 5, y => 20, z => [1, 2])
```

#### Using a custom constructor

If you'd rather want to deal with this in the class itself rather than in code that uses the class, you can amend the constructor to your liking.

Note that the default constructor `.new` calls `.bless` to actually allocate the object, which in turn calls `.BUILD` to handle initialization of attributes.

So the easiest way is to keep the default implementation of `.new`, but provide a custom `.BUILD`. You can map from named arguments to attributes directly in its signature, so the body of the `BUILD` routine can actually stay empty:

```perl
class Local::Class {
    has $.x;
    has $.y;
    has @.z;

    submethod BUILD (:$!x, :$!y, :@!z) { }
}

my %hash = x => 5, y => 20, z => [1, 2];
my $x = Local::Class.new(|%hash);

say $x;  # Local::Class.new(x => 5, y => 20, z => [1, 2])
```

Binding an array-in-an-item-container to a `@` parameter automatically removes the item container, so it doesn't suffer from the "array in an array" problem described above.

The downside is that you have to list all public attributes of your class in that `BUILD` parameter list. Also, you still have to interpolate the hash using `|` in the code that uses the class.

To get around both of those limitations, you can implement a custom `.new` like this:

```perl
class Local::Class {
    has $.x;
    has $.y;
    has @.z;

    method new (%attr) {
        self.bless: |Map.new: (.key => .value<> for %attr)
    }
}

my %hash = x => 5, y => 20, z => [1, 2];
my $x = Local::Class.new(%hash);

say $x;  # Local::Class.new(x => 5, y => 20, z => [1, 2])
```

Comment: This is great. But how do I turn `%( x => 5, z => [1, 2] )` into `\( x => 5, z => [1, 2] )`? How do I turn an already existing hash (like one read from a JSON string, for instance) into a suitable capture? I tried doing `Local::Class.new(%hash.Capture)`, but that results in the same issue you pointed out.

Comment: @jja I've updated the answer. (I turn it into a `Map` instead of a `Capture`, which is less messy but works the same for this purpose.)

Comment: Nice! However, I read that "writing your own `new` method [...] [is considered poor practice, because it makes correct initialization of objects from subclasses harder](https://docs.perl6.org/language/objects#Object_Construction)". Does that apply here as well? Or am I correct in thinking that this new `new` would only be called when the signature matched (=when passed a hash), and would therefore not have that problem?

Comment: @jja If you want it work **in addition** to the default `.new`, you have to define it as a multi-method, i.e. replace `method new` with `multi method new`.

Comment: If you want to create a class from a JSON blob, maybe the JSON::Unmarshal module can help you.

Comment: @timotimo That sounds useful, but in this case the JSON data I'm reading is an array of hashes, and I need to work with each hash in the array. By the time I have the hash, I am no longer working with JSON, and `JSON::Unmarshal` wants the JSON string. What I would need is something like `Hash::Unmarshal`.

Comment: i just submitted a pull request for JSON::Unmarshal that will allow you to `unmarshal($jsontext, Array[Dog])` or `unmarshal($jsontext, Hash[Dog])`. That should help, once it gets merged!

Comment: I use `BUILDALL` and `@a .= flatmap(*.flat)` to handle the json issue